# Compojure regex for matching a trailing slash

Tags: clojure, compojure

Maybe I'm just an idiot, but I can't set up a match for an optional trailing slash in Clojure.

```
lein repl
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 47383
user=> (use 'ring.mock.request 'clout.core)
nil
user=> (route-matches "/article/" (request :get "/article/"))
{}
user=> (route-matches "/article/?" (request :get "/article"))
nil
user=> (route-matches "/article/?" (request :get "/article/"))
nil
user=> (route-matches #"/article/?" (request :get "/article/"))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No implementation of method: :route-matches of protocol: #'clout.core/Route found for class: java.util.regex.Pattern (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

What regex can I use to match an optional trailing slash in Compojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path string expected by `clout` as the first argument to `route-matches` is not a regex, but a string that can contain keywords and the `*` wildcard.

I believe `clout` doesn't natively support defining routes that ignore a trailing slash. You could solve the problem with a middleware function that removes trailing slashes. The following functions were taken from an old version of the `compojure` source code (before the big refactoring), I couldn't find out if they moved to a new place. Here is the [original commit](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/commit/9cbd488ae35e7aed45c0c42f779ea1de13d3e8f3#src/compojure) that introduced these functions.

```
(defn with-uri-rewrite
  "Rewrites a request uri with the result of calling f with the
   request's original uri.  If f returns nil the handler is not called."
  [handler f]
  (fn [request]
    (let [uri (:uri request)
          rewrite (f uri)]
      (if rewrite
        (handler (assoc request :uri rewrite))
        nil))))

(defn- uri-snip-slash
  "Removes a trailing slash from all uris except \"/\"."
  [uri]
  (if (and (not (= "/" uri))
           (.endsWith uri "/"))
    (chop uri)
    uri))

(defn ignore-trailing-slash
  "Makes routes match regardless of whether or not a uri ends in a slash."
  [handler]
  (with-uri-rewrite handler uri-snip-slash))
```

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to avoid middleware. If it's the only way though, then OK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a condensed version of the middleware with no dependencies:

```clj
(defn with-ignore-trailing-slash [handler] (fn [request]
  (let [uri       (request :uri)
        clean-uri (if (and (not= "/" uri) (.endsWith uri "/"))
                    (subs uri 0 (- (count uri) 1))
                    uri)]
    (handler (assoc request :uri clean-uri)))))
```

Bug fix edits welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an even *more* compressed solution :)

```
(defn- with-ignore-trailing-slash [handler]
  (fn [request]
    (let [uri (request :uri)
          clean-uri (str/replace uri #"^(.+?)/+$" "$1")]
      (handler (assoc request :uri clean-uri)))))
```